# Can I still update my prior if I have been waiting a long time without observing any successes of a Poisson process?

Tags: bayesian, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution, posterior

This is related to my previous question: [How to update Poisson conjugate prior with observations of arrival time instead of counts?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260616/how-to-update-poisson-conjugate-prior-with-observations-of-arrival-time-instead)

Using the same notation, suppose $N \sim \operatorname{Pois}(\mu)$ is a Poisson distributed random variable, with interarrival times between observations distributed accordingly as $A \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\mu)$. Let $\mu$ be distributed according to the conjugate prior $\mu \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)$.

Suppose I start waiting for the next observation of my Poisson process, and I have waited a long time $t$ without observing any, that is, in time $t$, there are $n = 0$ observations. Is it possible to derive a posterior distribution for $\mu|n = 0, t$? Would it be:

$$\mu|n = 0, t \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta + t)$$

I am not sure how this is consistent with [Wikipedia article on updating the prior of an exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Bayesian_inference), as that explicitly relies on at least one observation of an interarrival time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only is it possible to update your prior for the observed waiting time, it is *necessary* to do this in order to faithfully capture the observed data.  What you are dealing with is a **censored observation** where the time until the event is known to be greater than the waiting time $t$.  Letting $n(t)$ be the number of arrivals at time $t$, you have $n(t) \sim \text{Pois}(\mu t)$.

The sampling distribution for your observation is:

$$p(n(t) = 0| \mu ) = \text{Pois}(0 | \mu t) = \exp (- \mu t).$$

Hence, your posterior distribution is:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
p(\mu | n(t) = 0) &\propto \exp(-\mu t) \cdot \mu^{\alpha -1} \exp(-\beta \mu) \\
&= \mu^{\alpha -1} \exp(- (\beta + t) \mu) \\
&\propto \text{Ga}(\mu |\alpha, \beta + t ).
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

So yes, you can derive the posterior, and your proposed posterior distribution is correct.